# mySQL select count, multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have three tables:

```
table1, table2, table3
```

I am trying to get a total count of rows from each table as well as sum of price column, so for example:

```
$r['count'] = total rows of all 3 tables combined;
$r['price'] = sum of all prices added together in all 3 tables combined;
```

Here is my query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count`, SUM(price) AS `price` FROM `table1` UNION
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count`, SUM(price) AS `price` FROM `table2` UNION
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count`, SUM(price) AS `price` FROM `table3`
```

When I run this query, I am getting:

```
count   price
19      5609399
8       946000
4       0
```

Which in turn does not work when looped out in PHP as they are 3 separate values and I am only being returned "count = 19 and price = 5609399". They don't all come out totaled together as `count` or `price`.

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count`, SUM(price) AS `price`
FROM
(
SELECT price from `table1` UNION ALL
SELECT price FROM `table2` UNION ALL
SELECT price FROM `table3`
) X
```

or generally to combine 3 pairs of values

```
select sum(`count`) `count`, sum(`price`) `price`
FROM
(
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count`, SUM(price) AS `price` FROM `table1` UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count`, SUM(price) AS `price` FROM `table2` UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count`, SUM(price) AS `price` FROM `table3`
) X
```

**Generally**, use UNION ALL when combining tables, not UNION because UNION removed duplicates, so if your count/sum were exactly

```
1, 100
1, 100
2, 200
```

A union query results in

```
1, 100    # duplicate collapsed
2, 200
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:

```
SELECT count(1) AS `count`, SUM(price) AS `price`
FROM (SELECT price FROM `table1`
      UNION ALL
      SELECT price FROM `table2`
      UNION ALL
      SELECT price FROM `table3`) AS `t`
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one as pattern for your tables -

```
SELECT
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1) + (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table2),
  (SELECT SUM(price) FROM table1) + (SELECT SUM(price) FROM table2);
```